# how does pop eax allow me to quit the func?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I don't understand how

```
pop eax
jmp eax
```

allow me to quit the function.

Here is the full code :

```
global _start

_start:
    call func
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

func:
    mov ebx, 42
    pop eax
    jmp eax
```

The global idea of this code is to have the exit code set to 42.

I guess there is something with the stack I don't understand

Comment: `pop eax; jmp eax` does the same thing as `ret` except it also trashes `eax`.

Comment: is there some benefit about using `pop eax; jmp eax` instead of `ret` ?

Comment: No.  There are a lot of drawbacks though, the worst one being that not returning with `ret` trashes the return predictor.

Comment: I got how it works ! Using `call` push the `eip` onto the stack. So when I pop `eax`, it will contain the instruction pointer, so I'm able to jump back to where I was before entering the function thanks to `jmp eax`

Comment: That's correct!  And `ret` does pretty much that.  It's effectively `pop eip`.